# PHP - Using PDO connections across classes

Tags: php, oop, pdo

[Edited/Updated]

Allow me to explain the situation. I have three files:

Below is db.class.php. When called, it connects to the DB in the constructor and closes the connection in the destructor. If you notice the query() method, it's simply a static INSERT at the moment, as that is where I'm stuck.

```
<?php
//
// Class: db.class.php
// Desc: Connects to a database and runs PDO queries via MySQL
// Settings:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Db
{
    # Class properties
    private $DBH; // Database Handle
    private $STH; // Statement Handle

    # Func: __construct()
    # Desc: Connects to DB
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Connection information
        $host   = 'localhost';
        $dbname = 'removed';
        $user   = 'removed';
        $pass   = 'removed';

        // Attempt DB connection
        try
        {
            $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
            $this->DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo 'Successfully connected to the database!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    # Func: query(sql statement)
    # Desc: Sends a query to the DB
    public function query($sql_statement)
    {
        $sql = array(':color' => $sql_statement);
        $this->STH = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO color_table (color) value ( :color )");
        $this->STH->execute($sql);
    }

    # Func: __destruct()
    # Desc: Disconnects from the DB
    public function __destruct()
    {
        // Disconnect from DB
        $this->DBH = null;
        echo 'Successfully disconnected from the database!';
    }
}
?>
```

Below is colors.class.php. For now, it only has an insert function. What I'm trying to do is essentially rip the what I have in the query() function from db.class.php and put it into the insertColor() function here, and pass the entire SQL statement whether it's an insert, delete, or update to the query() function.

```
<?php
//
// Class: colors.class.php
// Desc: Provides methods to create a query to insert,
//       update, or delete a color from the database.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Colors
{
    # Class properties
    protected $db;

    # Func: __construct()
    # Desc: Passes the Db object so we can send queries
    public function __construct(Db $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    # Func: insertColor()
    # Desc: Sends an INSERT querystring
    public function insertColor($color)
    {
        $this->db->query($color);
        echo 'Inserted color:' . $color;
    }
}
?>
```

Below we have colors.php which is where everything above is instantiated and implemented. So here is where I'd pass what color I actually want to be inserted into the database.

```
<?php
Require('db.class.php');
Require('colors.class.php');

$db = new Db;
$colors = new Colors($db);
$colors->insertColor('TestColor'); // Passing the color here to be put into an insert statement

?>
```

Where I'm essentially stuck is I'm trying to make the colors.class.php create a PDO statement, and then pass it to the db.class.php query() method when they're ready to run. Right now, the PDO statement is simply defined in the query() method but I'm trying to avoid this. Essentially, I want to rip what I have out of the query() method and split it into three methods in the Colors class, one for insert, update, and delete.

However, I'm rather new to OOP programming and am having issues with all of the syntax, nor to I know if this is even a good approach. Any help is greatly appreciated, and let me know if more details or information is needed.

Comment: isn't require(), like all functions and variables, case sensitive?

Comment: @ReyGonzales [Functions are not case sensitive](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xx25sE), although variables are. `require` is not actually a function, it's a language construct - and these are also case-insensitive.

Comment: ftr, require* or include* are not functions, rather they are statements. So they should be written as `require 'db.class.php';`

Comment: @ReyGonzales PHP is case insensitive!

Comment: @Besnik Variable names are case-sensitive, as are (by default) constant names.

Comment: @MikePurcell Parenthesis can be used with `require` and `include`, but they are optional. That is yet another area where PHP is very inconsistent, as the rules differ from one language construct to the next - for example `isset()` and `empty()`, while they are language constructs as well, require identical syntax to function calls. `exit`/`die` can be called with parens if you are passing a value or without if you are not. `if` statements require parens around the condition expression, ternary statements do not. It is most annoying.

Comment: I've made progress here and now I'm stuck trying to prepare the PDO statements separately in the Colors class, then pass them to the query() method in the Db class. I've updated my post with information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, because `$db` is a local variable inside the method. Pass it as an argument:

```
class Colors
{
  protected $db;

  public function __construct(Db $db = null)
  {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function insertColor()
  {
    if ($this->db != null)
    {
      $this->db->query();
    }
  }
}
```

And `query` is a method so you have to add the brackets: `$db->query()`

Comment: Recommending global as a solution to an OP tagged as OOP is not a good idea.

Comment: @MikePurcell You're right! I removed the first approach. It was just quick and dirty...

Comment: Closer, but no cigar. I updated my post with the problem I ran into. Thanks for the help so far everyone!

Comment: @Xenostar You have to pass your database instance to the new colors object:`$colors = new Colors($db);`

Comment: It appears that you've set $db as a __construct argument, which is null, because you didn't actually pass it when you constructed the object.

Answer (score 3):

I would remove the inclusion and initialization of the database from your class file and put it in `colors.php` itself. Then you pass the `$db` as an argument to the constructor:

```
<?php
Require('db.class.php');
Require('colors.class.php');

$db = new Db;

$colors = new Colors($db);
$colors->insertColor();
?>
```

I would also remove the default value in your constructor as your `Colors` class will not work without the database:

```
public function __construct(Db $db)    // constructor Colors class
```

Lastly I would look into [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) of classes so that you don't have to require them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$db->query;` to `$db->query();`

Also, $db will need to be declared as a global to access it like that. Might want to consider making it a private property of `Colors`

Comment: @Besnik Fixed. Thanks for borrowing the rest of my answer and downvoting me so you can gain a few extra points though